# Tangent bundle of sphere as a complex manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to show that the tangent bundle, $TS^n$ of the n-sphere $S^n$ is diffeomorphic to the set $\sum z_i^2 = 1$ in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$.

It's relatively straightforward to see that the tangent bundle of the sphere can be identified with:

$$TS^n = \{ (x_0,...,x_n,y_0,...,y_n) : x_i,y_i \in \mathbb{R}, \sum x_i^2 = 1, \sum x_i y_i = 0 \}$$

Now to show this diffeomorphism I tried the natural thing of writing $z_j = x_j + iy_j$ but now we have $\sum z_j^2 = 1 - \sum y_i^2$ so it only lies in the required subspace if we restrict the tangent spaces of the sphere. I'm wondering how to write down a different map that does this?

I'm also a little concerned about how to show such a map is a diffeomorphism, how could I show that the identification I've made above as the tangent bundle embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{2(n+1)}$ is smooth? It's probably obvious but I'm struggling to see it!

Thanks for any help

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but shouldn't it be $\sum x_i^2=1$?

Comment: Wait, why are $x_i$ and $y_i$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$?

Comment: I think it definitively should be $x_i,y_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\sum x_i^2=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, yes there were a couple of typos which I've now corrected!

Comment: I think you then also want to consider $\sum z_j\bar{z}_j$ instead of $\sum z_j$.

Comment: What do you mean by "the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$"?

Comment: Yes, you mean the hyperquadric $\sum z_j^2 = 1$ in $\Bbb C^{n+1}$. This is very non-compact and hardly a unit circle or unit sphere.

Comment: @TedShifrin Indeed, for some reason I was thinking of that as a circle - it's clearly not, thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $Q\subseteq\mathbf C^{n+1}$ be the affine quadric defined by the equation $\sum z_i^2=1$. The map 
$$
f\colon TS^n\rightarrow Q
$$
defined by
$$
z=f(x,y)=x\sqrt{1+||y||^2}+y\sqrt{-1}
$$
does the job, where $||y||^2=\sum y_i^2$. Indeed,
one has $f(x,y)\in Q$ since
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n z_i^2=\sum_{i=0}^n x_i^2(1+||y||^2)-y^2_i+2x_iy_i\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{1+||y||^2}=\\
1+||y||^2-||y||^2+2\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{1+||y||^2}\sum x_iy_i=1,
$$
for $(x,y)\in TS^n$.

The map $f$ is a diffeomorphism since its inverse is
$$
g\colon Q\rightarrow TS^n
$$
defined by
$$
g(z)=\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+||y||^2}}, y\right),
$$
where $z=x+y\sqrt{-1}$.
One has $g(z)\in TS^n$ since
$$
||x||^2-||y||^2=1
$$
and
$$
2\sqrt{-1}\sum x_iy_i=0
$$
for $z\in Q$.

Comment: Excellent: +1. I have already seen that calculation, but I don't remember where. Would you happen to know in what context these calculations arise?

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg: I don't know about the specific calculation, but the general context is the one of Totaro's good complexifications (see http://www.math.ucla.edu/~totaro/papers/public_html/complex.pdf). A good complexification of a smooth manifiold $M$ is a smooth affine real algebraic variety $X$ such that $X(\mathbf R)$ is diffeomorphic to $M$, and the inclusion $X(\mathbf R)\rightarrow X(\mathbf C)$ is a homotopy equivalence. The manifold $S^n$ is particularly simple example of a manifold admitting a good complexification.

Comment: Dear Johannes: thanks a lot for your explanations and reference. I find it quite interesting that this rather elementary question is related to quite advanced research by a brilliant mathematician like Totaro, who seems to have a knack for addressing difficult mathematical problems through rather unsophisticated considerations.

Comment: there is a slight error in the equation (I won't mess with your post). In the last terms it is $\dots 2x_iy_i\sqrt{-(1+|y|^2)}$ and not $2x_iy_i\sqrt{-1}$. That does not affect the result of course (the inner product of $x$ and $y$ is still $0$). Thanks for the beautiful answer

Comment: @Jose You're right. Thank you!