# Does the tangent space to $SO(3)$ have additional useful structure?

Tags: manifolds, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

The tangent space to $SO(3)$ at the identity can be identified as the space of all skew symmetric matrices $Skew_3$.

At other points $X$, we can see that the tangent space is the set of all matrices $Y$ such that $Y X^t + X Y^t = 0$, or $(YX^t) = -(YX^t)^t$.

1. Are these known by any specific name?
2. Why aren't these set of matrices $Y$ studied, except when $X=\mathbb{I}$?

I wonder if we can impose additional (useful) structure, such as an inner product (and therefore a norm) on $Skew_3$ so that we can reason about its "shape."

3. Is it flat, like the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$ or is it a curved space?  The reason I ask is because tangents to curves/spaces embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (e.g., circle) or $\mathbb{R}^3$ (e.g., sphere) look flat (line and plane respectively).  I am curious whether this intuition that tangent spaces are "flat" translates to other manifolds.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784898/tangent-bundle-of-sphere-as-a-complex-manifold/1785524

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908137/tangent-bundle-of-the-2-sphere

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the links @cactus314!  The links answer my intuitions about (3).  Do you have any pointers for (1) or (2)?

Comment: ad 1), that's the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}_3$ I guess, but since you already put the tag "lie-algebras" in there, I would assume you know that, and all the nice things one can find about a Lie group via its Lie algebra? ad 2), if I recall correctly, the tangent spaces at different points of a Lie group are all isomorphic, using the group structure (isomorphisms from the space at $1$ to the space at an arbitrary $g$ induced by either left or right multiplication with $g$).

Comment: Thanks @TorstenSchoeneberg.  For (2), it didn't occur to me that tangent spaces at different points are isomorphic to each other (it makes sense since $X$ is a rotation, so it's invertible by $X^t$).  For (1), while I know it has a Lie Algebra structure, but I wondered if it can be endowed with any other structure (such as a suitably defined inner product) that is useful in practice.

Comment: Re inner product: On any Lie algebra, one has the Killing form https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form; if the Lie algebra is simple, the Killing form is non-degenerate; if further the Lie algebra (resp. the group it comes from) is compact, the Killing form is negative definite. All conditions are met in this example. Further, the Killing form is unique up to a scalar among the symmetric bilinear forms on the algebra which satisfy a certain invariance property.

Answer (score 1):

1) The tangent space at each point is a copy of $\mathfrak{so}_3$ (aka $Skew_3$). As $SO(3)$ is a Lie group all of its tangent spaces are isomorphic and carry the structure of a Lie algebra.

2) I'm not 100% sure on this but I think the relation you have described is simply created by the action of conjugation of the element $X \in SO(3)$ on the relation $Y^t = - Y$ and so studying it is equivalent to studying $\mathfrak{so}_3$ as the set of skew-symmetric matrices (remember that defining it with matrices already involves a choice of basis and this would be equivalent to that)

3) All tangent spaces are vector bundles. That is at each point the tangent space is a vector space which is a fundamentally flat object.